# META REFRESH calls javascript to go back (in history) but needs to send variable to that script.

Tags: php, javascript, url, redirect

```
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=javascript:history.go(-1)">';
```

Here is what I have at the end of a PHP script that updates data into a MySql db. It goes back to the edit page with the meta refresh (where I want it to go).

However the `edit.php` script contains a `GET variable` (edit.php?variable=value) so it knows what information to pull from the db.  This variable also carries over onto the `update.php` script (update.php?variable=value).

I would like to be able to add `&action=updated` to the end of the URL after it goes back to the php page so it would look like `edit.php?variable=value&action=updated`.

*I have tried to GET POST and ECHO the variable in the update.php script into the edit.php script redirect but with no luck.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the PHP Header function instead of printing out the meta tag, so it would be like this:

```
header("Location:update.php?variable=".$value."&action=updated");
```

Comment: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /update.php:29) in update.php on line 106

This is the error I get.

Comment: header has to be called before you send any other headers to the server, it seems that you are outputting something before you call it. Could you show us some more code?

Comment: Never mind I figured it out with doing a mashed up meta refresh: see below

Comment: <meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=
edit.php?variable=<?php
if($_GET['variable']){
$variable = $_GET['variable'];
}
echo$variable
?>
&action=updated
">

Comment: Then post it as an answer and validate it :)